# Hiding then showing a div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, callback

I want to *slideUp* some divs, then *slideDown* 1 div. However, I'm having some issues.

```
$("#divDocument,#divLocation").slideUp("normal", function()
    { $("#divSearch").slideDown("normal", doStuff()); });
```

With this code, *divDocument* is visible, *divLocation* isn't. Because the *divLocation* is already hidden the *doStuff()* event fires immediately, even though *divDocument* isn't hidden yet.

```
$("#divDocument).slideUp("normal", function()
    { $("#divSearch").slideDown("normal", doStuff()); });
```

This code works fine, as it waits until *divDocument* is fully hidden before calling *doStuff()*. Am I using the multiple element selector wrong here? Am I doing something else incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If divLocation is already visible, why not hide it first?

```
$("#divDocument,#divLocation").hide().slideUp("normal", function() { 
    $("#divSearch").slideDown("normal", doStuff()); 
});
```

**EDIT**:
Sorry, I got confused. slideUp is meant to HIDE the elements. For some reason I thought it was meant to show them. In that case, you could do this:

```
$("#divDocument,#divLocation").filter(':visible').slideUp("normal", function() { 
    $("#divSearch").slideDown("normal", doStuff()); 
});
```

With the `:visible` filter it would only do the `slideUp` on whichever element(s) are visible so they can then be hidden with `slideUp`. I am guessing this is what you are looking for since there's no point in hiding an already hidden element. If you want to momentarily show the hidden one and then `slideUp` it, you can just switch my original answer from `hide()` to `show()` and then do the `slideUp`.

Comment: This does hide the divs before showing divSearch, but I lose the slideUp effect by doing this. I would really like to keep the effect for consistency.

Comment: Your revision nearly works perfectly. It does exactly what I want, however, if both the divs are already hidden it never calls the callback. This has pointed me in the right direction though, I forgot you could filter a result like. Thanks!

Comment: I've posted my final code as an answer, so you can see how I got around this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I ended up using. Thanks, Paolo, for pointing me in the right direction with the filter.

```
var o = $("#divDocument,#divLocation").filter(':visible');
if (o.length > 0) {
    o.slideUp("normal",
    function() {
        $("#divSearch").slideDown("normal", doStuff);
    });
}
else {
    doStuff();
}
```